# Avatar not placed correctly on a podium CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm just wondering how to make an avatar-person stand on a podium (another image). Here is an example what I mean. I want the avatar-person to stand on the podium like in picture B.

I've played around with it and it turns out wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: dude, accept some answers. Nice pic though. :)

Comment: What is the CSS of your image (not the background but the avatar?) Also, are you sure the avatar shouldn't go into the avatar holder?

Comment: Your positioning is off. need more left/top offsets.

Comment: We don't own the virtual avatars, they're linked from a game. We're a fansite!

Comment: Also amon I tried putting it inside the div itself, but it doesn't work for what I want it to turn out like in picture B.

Comment: @user1482117 so *what* went wrong when you put the avatar inside the `div`? What did you try?

Comment: What has php got to do it with it?

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the code is this:

```
<img src="/path/to/avatar" />
<div id="avatar-holder"></div>
```

You specified the image before the `div`, so it appears atop. We want the avatar over it.

So lets change the html to:

```
<div id="avatar-holder">
   <img src="/path/to/avatar" />
</div>
```

We want to position our image freely, so we do this:

```
#avatar-holder {position:static;}
#avatar-holder > img {position:absolute;}
/* OR:
#avatar-holder > img {position:relative;}
*/
```

Now you fiddle with the `top`/`left` property of the image, possibly assigning negative pixel values, until it looks right. Only works for images that are always the same size, or we need something more complex. YOu could also do the layout using *margins*, but I don't think that's elegant.

If the result should have the avatar covering your text boxes, just add a `margin-top` to the avatar holder.

When using background images, you might also want to use `no-repeat`; of the properties you did use, `color` and `text-shadow` are completely useless here.